# How to use gnu make to build all targets with a particular suffix?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given a `Makefile` with multiple targets having the same suffix:

```
./foo/foo.zip: ./foo/foo.txt
    do_something -i ./foo/foo.txt -o ./foo/foo.zip

./bar/bar.zip: ./bar/bar.txt
    do_something -i ./bar/bar.txt -o ./bar/bar.zip
```

It is easy enough to create an `all` target by hand:

```
all-zips: ./foo/foo.zip ./bar/bar.zip

.PHONY: all-zips
```

**How can the all target be specified to build all targets ending in a particular suffix?**

I'm looking for something like

```
all-zips: *.zip
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that: there's no way to compute a set of targets defined in a makefile.

The best you could do would be to find all the base files (which always exist) then construct the names of the targets from them.

So given your example it could be something like:

```
# find all the text files
TXT_FILES := $(shell find . -name \*.txt)

# transform them into the targets to be built
ZIP_FILES := $(TXT_FILES:.txt=.zip)

all: $(ZIP_FILES)
```